# Why the UISlider is slow to update the value in Cocoa-Touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am developing in `Objective-C` and IOS8 for `BLE`.

I have two file named **`BLEConnect.m`** and **`BTServer.m`**. There has `UILabel` and `UISlider` in **`BLEConnect.m`**.

The **`BLEConnect.m`** using **`BTServer.m`** to get the data , After **`BTServer.m`** has receive data , it will send the data to the **`BLEConnect.m`**.

**Operation process**

**1.** call **`[self.defaultBTServer readValue:chara];`** in **`BLEConnect.m` when click the button(**`SyncLEDState`**)**

**2.** When The function **`readValue`** has been called , the auto feed back function **`didUpdateValueForCharacteristic`** will feed back the data. And it will send data to the function **`updateLEDstate`** in **`BLEConnect.m`**

**3.** When the function **`updateLEDstate`** in **`BLEConnect.m`** has get the data from **`BTServer.m`** , it will update the value to the **`UISlider`**.

The **`BTServer.m`** get the data well , and it also send the data to the **`BLEConnect.m`**.

But I saw the log in the **`updateLEDstate`** in the **`BLEConnect.m`**. The **`NSLog(@"updateLEDstate end!!");`** already show and I'm sure the data is correct. But the **`UISlider`** is very slow to update...

The partial correlation code is like the following:

In **`BLEConnect.m`**

```
    #import "BLEConnect.h"
    #import "BTServer.h"
    #import "ProgressHUD.h"
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

        @interface BLEConnect () <BTServerDelegate>
         @property (strong,nonatomic) BTServer *defaultBTServer;
        @end

        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            self.defaultBTServer = [BTServer defaultBTServer];
            self.defaultBTServer.delegate=(id)self;
            [self.defaultBTServer initBLEConnect:self];

            [self.WhiteSlider setMinimumValue:0];
            [self.WhiteSlider setMaximumValue:100];
            self.WhiteSlider.value = 100;
        }


        - (IBAction)SyncLEDState:(id)sender {

            for(CBCharacteristic *chara in self.defaultBTServer.discoveredSevice.characteristics){      
                if ([chara.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:LEDStateCharacteristicUUID]]) {

                 //call the function readValue in BTServer.m
                 [self.defaultBTServer readValue:chara];
                }
            }
        }

        - (void)updateLEDstate:(NSMutableArray*)LEDstate
        {
            // get the data from BTServer.m , and update the value.
            //But it is slow to change the value......
            self.RedSlider.value = [[LEDstate objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
            NSLog(@"updateLEDstate end!!");
        }
```

In **`BTServer.h`**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>
#import "PeriperalInfo.h"
#import "BLEConnect.h"

@class BLEConnect;

+(BTServer*)defaultBTServer;
-(void)initBLEConnect:(BLEConnect *) BLEconnect;
```

In **`BTServer.m`**

```
#import "BTServer.h"
#import "BLEConnect.h"

+(BTServer*)defaultBTServer
{
    if (nil == _defaultBTServer) {
        _defaultBTServer = [[BTServer alloc]init];
        [_defaultBTServer initBLE];
    }
    return _defaultBTServer;
}

-(void)initBLEConnect:(BLEConnect *)BLEconnect
{   //receive the BLEConnect class object.
    self.defaultBLEConnect = BLEconnect;
}

-(void)readValue:(CBCharacteristic*)characteristic
{
    [self.selectPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:self.selectCharacteristic];

    /*!!!!When this function been call , the feedback function didUpdateValueForCharacteristic will be call. The data is get by characteristic.value . */
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSString *LEDstate = [self getHEX:characteristic.value];

    //get the data and put into NSMutableArray.
    NSMutableArray * LEDstateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
   [LEDstateArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:LEDstate]];

    //send the NSMutableArray to updateLEDstate function in BLEConnect.m
    [self.defaultBLEConnect updateLEDstate:LEDstateArray];
}
```

**Why the UISlider is slow to update the value in Objective-c ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:` and related methods don't guarantee callback on the main queue. However, you always must update UI on the main thread.

Use `dispatch_async` to dispatch your `UISlider` code on the main queue.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear!